# Mysql sort aggregated rows by date

Tags: mysql, datetime, sorting, scalability

I think this is a simple question: I'm just new to php and can't really figure this out in an efficient way. What I want to do is for each friend, query all the posts and return a single list thats sorted by the date. But they are two different tables and I don't really understand how the tables could be joined with a single statement nor if this is even the best scalable solution. Help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You would really need to tell us the structure of the tables and how you want the results so we could write the query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM friends
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.author_id = friends.id
ORDER BY posts.created_at
```

Comment: I'm yet to implement it but this seems right. Thanks. Now I hate to ask another question but would your solution be faster/more scalable than something akin to this:
"select ... 
from posts 
where user_id 
in ($user_array) 
order by time desc";
I would probably have to do a prior call to pull the array but I don't know the efficiency of a join.

Comment: `JOIN` is efficient as long as you have indexes.